# item in flatlist does not refresh

Tags: react-native

I want to change tintcolor of a picture when pressing on touchanbleopacity

I wrote this code, but when i press, tintcolor changes in array, but not in flatlist.

```
…;
let posts = [some_data]

const SomeScreen = ({navigation}) => {
    …
    function setColor(item){
        if (posts[item.id].color == 'red'){
            posts[item.id].color = '#8B8D8E'
            posts[item.id].bgColor = '#232323'
        }
        else{
            posts[item.id].color = 'red'
            posts[item.id].bgColor = '#3E2526'
        }
    }
    
    return(
       …
            <FlatList
                data={posts}
                keyExtractor={item=>item.id}
                extraData={posts}
                refreshControl={
                    <RefreshControl
                      refreshing={refreshing}
                      onRefresh={onRefresh}
                    />
                  }
                renderItem={({item}) =>{
                    …

<TouchableOpacity onPress={() => {setColor(item)}}>
    <View style={…}>
        <Image source={…} style={{…, tintColor: item.likeColor}}/>
    </View>
</TouchableOpacity>
</View>
</FlatList>
   …
);
}

…
```

I tried to use extraData, but nothing happened.

How can i fix it?

Comment: Hi, if you want to change UI your data should be in state, then it will works, also setting colors should happens in setState function in posts state or locally in flatlist item component state, I want to say UI only rerendera ( change ) when current state or parent component state changes